# JS Dynamic import map from npm package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, package, dynamic-import

I want to import some npm packages like what we normally do in webpack but in pure  js import :

```
import package from 'package-name'
```

but currently in pure js import we must :

```
import package from '/node_modules/package-name.js'
```

does anybody know the way to set some path mapping to pure javascript `import`?

Comment: If you are using npm the default path is the node_modules why do you need to specify it? Have you tried `resolveLoader`? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloader

Comment: i dont want to use web pack i want to use native ecma script import

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this : [deep module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias).
This will help you define custom module aliases for your scripts.

Though you don't need this unless you are using your own modules.